# Vector pointing at Vectors

Tags: c++, containers

I am trying to implement a vector that points to other vectors and than extracting the value of the second vector by using indexes. For example I want to index the 3 value of a vector by inedexing it through the first vector;

I get some vector index out of range and i cant understand why.
Here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;


    int main() {
        int n = 2;



            vector <vector<int>*> vec1;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {
                vector<int> vec;
                vec.clear();
                cout << "Enter number of var : ";
                int var;
                cin >> var;
                for (int i = 0; i < var; i++)
                {
                    cout << "Enter number : ";
                    int num ;
                    cin >> num;
                    vec.push_back(num);
                }
                vec1.push_back(&vec);
                cout << "Container ends \n";
            }
            cout << "Enter i : ";
            int i;
            cin >> i;
            cout << "Enter j : ";
            int j;
            cin >> j;
            auto newvec = vec1[i];
            cout << newvec->at(j);
            system("pause");


        return 0;
    }
```

What I actually did is this. But i don't know if this is a good way to do it. I allocate the vectors in the heap.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<map>

#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;


    int main() {
        int n = 2;



            vector <vector<int>*> vec1;

            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
            {
                vector<int> *vec = new vector<int>;
                vec->clear();
                cout << "Enter number of var : ";
                int var;
                cin >> var;
                for (int i = 0; i < var; i++)
                {
                    cout << "Enter number : ";
                    int num ;
                    cin >> num;
                    vec->push_back(num);
                }
                vec1.push_back(vec);
                cout << "Container ends \n";
            }
            cout << "Enter i : ";
            int i;
            cin >> i;
            cout << "Enter j : ";
            int j;
            cin >> j;
            auto newvec = vec1[i];
            cout << newvec->at(j) << endl;;
            system("pause");


        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: You're keeping pointers to `vector` that have been destroyed (created and destroyed inside your `for`).

Comment: @Stephen Newell You are wright i just sow it. But still i cant think of a way to do hat i am trying to do

Comment: `vector<int> vec;` is inside of the `for()` loops scope. All references _addresses_ will be dangling after the `for()` loop has finished.

Comment: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>` -- What is the reason for not using this?  Or better yet, a `std::vector<int>` and manage it like a 2D array?  And also, using raw pointers does *not* make you a better C++ programmer, with all due respect.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie you are wright. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***out of range *** values is due to `vector<int> vec` inside the `for` loop and/or maybe to `i` and `j`.

- So, to store a `pointer` use a `pointer`: use something like `vector<int> vec = new vector<int>()`.

With your implementation: at the end of the `for` loop, the variable`vec` is removed and its address maybe used by another variable. So when you try to get its value, it is quite possible that you do not get what you have stored.

- Then, Make sure when you get `i` and `j` that: `i` is between `0` and `n-1`. `j` is between `0` and `var-1` of the vector.

Hope it helps you.